# How to include vitamio library in Android Studio

Tags: android, vitamio

I have difficulties including the Vitamio Library in Android Studio.

How should i include it in my project?

Should i include only the Vitamio folder inside the VitamioBundle folder?

Comment: You should choose an accepted answer for your questions

Answer (score 14):

In your build.gradle add

```
dependencies { 
  compile 'me.neavo:vitamio:4.2.2'
}
```

Comment: can we use Vitamio library to download streaming videos?

Answer (score 1):

Open AS, File -> New -> Import Moudle, add "compile project(':vitamio')" in gradle dependencies

Answer (score 0):

- Download Vitamio Library from [here](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle).
- Extract the download.
- From Android Studio-> Select File-> New-> Project-> Android-> Android Project From Existing code-> Import Vitamio from the extracted folder (it will be imported in the name of "InitActivity").
- Then go to your Project Properties-> Android-> Library-> Add InitActivity

If you want to refer some samples you may import vitamio-sample from the download.it may help you to understand the work flow of Vitamio